# Check for existence of directory in Perl with wildcard

Tags: perl

I need to check whether any of a set of directories exist in a Perl script. The directories are named in the format XXXX*YYY - I need to check for each XXXX and enter an if statement if true.

In my script I have two variables $monitor_location (contains the path to the root directory being scanned) and $clientid (contains the XXXX).

The code snippet below has been expanded to show more of what I'm doing. I have a query which returns each client ID, I'm then looping for each record returned and trying to calculate the disk space used by that client ID.

I have the following code so far (doesn't work):

```
# loop for each client
while ( ($clientid, $email, $name, $max_record) = $query_handle1->fetchrow_array() )
{
  # add leading zeroes to client ID if needed
  $clientid=sprintf"%04s",$clientid;

  # scan file system to check how much recording space has been used
  if (-d "$monitor_location/$clientid\*") {
    # there are some call recordings for this client
    $str = `du -c $monitor_location/$clientid* | tail -n 1 2>/dev/null`;
    $str =~ /^(\d+)/;
    $client_recspace = $1;
    print "Client $clientid has used $client_recspace of $max_record\n";
  }
}
```

To be clear, I want to enter the if statement if there are any folders that start with XXXX.

Hope this makes sense! Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [glob](http://p3rl.org/glob) to expand the wildcard:

```
for my $dir (grep -d, glob "$monitor_location/$clientid*") {
   ...
}
```

Comment: I've edited the code in the question to better show what I'm trying to achieve. Struggling to see how I can fit the above into my code, would appreciate a little input? Thanks

Comment: @btongeorge: If you just want to know whether such dirs exist, you can use `if (grep -d, glob "$...")`.

Answer (score 1):

I have a "thing" against glob.  (It seems to only work once (for me), meaning you couldn't re-glob that same dir again later in the same script.  It's probably just me, though.)

I prefer readdir().  This is definitely longer, but it WFM.

```
chdir("$monitor_location") or die;
open(DIR, ".") or die;
my @items = grep(-d, grep(/^$clientid/, readdir(DIR)));
close(DIR);
```

Everything in @items matches what you want.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. So putting this in the context of my original code, I need to run the du line to get the combined size of all the directories with the same client ID for each ID in @items. How could I go about that?

Comment: @jimtut: `glob` creates an iterator in scalar context. That might be the source of your failure with it.

Comment: `glob` usually DWIM but it has its idiosyncracies and unintuitive uses. It's good to keep non-`glob` solutions in mind.